How to test function inside Fyne API ConfirmDialog
Using the Fyne library, I'm using a ConfirmDialog to confirm wether a user wants to overwrite a save file.
func (g *GunMenu) LoadButton(w *fyne.Window) (sb *widget.Button) {
    g.SaveButton = widget.NewButton("save", func() {
        fmt.Println("saving...")
        dialog.ShowConfirm("Saving...", "overwrite save?", func(b bool) {
            err := g.SaveData.SaveGame()
            if err != nil {
                dialog.NewError(err, *w)
            }
        }, *w)
    })

    return g.SaveButton
}

However, when I try to test it I can only reach the code where the test clicks on the button but I'm not able choose how to click the confirm button or the dismiss button.
func TestGetWidgets(t *testing.T) {
    tw := test.NewWindow(nil)
    gm := GunMenu{}
    gm.LoadButton(&tw)
    test.Tap(gm.SaveButton)
    test.Tap(gm.SaveButton)
}

Are there any approaches to testing the dialog? Would the callback have to be another function defined elsewhere and then that could be unit tested by itself?
Doing it this way, I can't seem to hit the dialog function inside so this won't get covered during testing.

That's a good question. I always just test the code that will be triggered separately (i.e. make it a different function that is called from the dialog ) then it can be unit tested more easily.
It might be a good idea to open a feature request for some dialog testing helpers to be added in the test package though?
